# Switching between two tables depending on width

Tags: css

I need to switch between two tables depending on device width (my case is unusual because the customer needs different tables each device, so I can't make an only one responsive table).

My problem is very simple, I'm trying with @media and display properties:

```
@media all and (min-width: 769px){
    table :nth-of-type(1){display:block}
    table :nth-of-type(2){display:none}
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px){
    table :nth-of-type(1){display:none}
    table :nth-of-type(2){display:block}
}
```

but I only get two tables (first case) or none (second case).

How I must use selectors in order to set right display each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I always use the @media like this: "@media only screen and...".
The different to "@media all and" is the screen will not interact with printer or speech-screenreader types.

I´m not sure why you want to use the selector :nth-of-type() for your table. As workaround you could define your table in a div and hide the whole div.

So if you want to hide the div the code should look like this:

```css
    @media all and (min-width: 769px){
     #table_1 {display:block}
     #table_2 {display:none}
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 768px){
    #table_1 {display:none}
    #table_2 {display:block}
    }
```